# Apply relative references to a formula in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

When posting the formula below in an Excel cell directly the correct results are displayed. However, when adding this to the VBA to refresh, when new data is uploaded, no output is given.

Excel formula :

> =IF(VLOOKUP([@[Account Name and ID]], FirstTimeDonor!$A$3:$C$5000, 3, FALSE)=[@Date], "FTD", "Non-FTD")

VBA:

```
tbl.ListColumns("First Time Donation").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = _
"=IF(VLOOKUP([@[Account Name and ID]], FirstTimeDonor!$A$3:$C$5000, 3, FALSE)=[@Date], 1, 0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change `.FormulaR1C1` to `.Formula`

---

```
...DataBodyRange.Formula = "=IF(VLOOKUP([@[Account Name and ID]], FirstTimeDonor!$A$3:$C$5000, 3, FALSE)=[@Date], 1, 0)"
```

Answer (score -1):

FormulaR1C1-your formula is using absolute references, not relative ones. Use just DataBodyRange.Formula= instead.